# Let $\sim$ be a relation on $\mathbb R$ by $x \sim y \iff x-y \in\mathbb Q$. Show that $\sqrt{3} \notin \left[\sqrt{2}\right]$.

Tags: solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let $\sim$ be a relation on $\mathbb R$ by $x \sim y \iff x-y \in\mathbb Q$. Show that $\sqrt{3} \notin \left[\sqrt{2}\right]$.

We will use the fact that $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational. (Small proof) Suppose $\sqrt 6 = \frac ab,$ is rational and $\gcd (a,b)=1$. Then we have $\sqrt 6 = \frac ab \implies 6 = \frac {a^2}{b^2} \implies 2(3b^2) = a^2 \implies a=2k, k\in\mathbb Z$. We have $2(3b^2) = 4k^2 \implies 3b^2 = 2k^2 \implies b$ is even, a contradiction.

Assume that $\sqrt{3} \sim \sqrt{2} \implies \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb Q$. Let $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} = \frac ab$ for $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. Squaring both sides we have $\frac{a^2}{b^2} = 3 - 2\sqrt{6} + 2$. By "Small proof" above, $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational. Thus, we have an irrational number on the right and a rational on the left. A contradiction. Thus $\sqrt 3 \notin \left[\sqrt{2}\right]$.

Is this a valid argument/proof? In addition, is it correct to say $\left[\sqrt{2}\right] = \left\{\sqrt 2\right\}$? (No, refer to comments below)

Comment: Looks good, though I do not know what you mean by $[\sqrt 2]=\{\sqrt 2\}$.  Do you possibly mean $[\sqrt 2]=[\{\sqrt 2\}]$?  That claim is true (where, in my expression $\{\sqrt 2\}$ refers to the fractional part of $\sqrt 2$.)

Comment: @lulu, because $\sqrt{2} \sim \sqrt 2 \implies\sqrt 2 - \sqrt 2 = 0\in\mathbb Q$. At least, that is what it seems to me.

Comment: But what does $[\sqrt 2]=\{\sqrt 2\}$ mean to you?  It is common enough to use $\{x\}$ to denote the fractional part of a real number $x$, but that would not explain what you wrote.

Comment: $[\sqrt 2] = \{\sqrt 2\}$ means the only elements that relates to $\sqrt 2$ (using the definition of our relation we have imposed on $\mathbb R$) means $\sqrt 2$ is the only element from $\mathbb R$ that relates to $\sqrt 2$. Thus $\sqrt 2$ is the only element in that particular class, namely $[\sqrt 2]$.

Comment: Well, that's obviously false.  Indeed $\sqrt 2 \sim (\sqrt 2 +1)$, for one example.

Comment: I see. My bad... :( I will fix my post.